# How to convert openCV results to svg or stl locally?

Tags: android, kotlin, opencv, svg, stl

I’m learning kotlin development at school. For my project I’ve decided to generate a 3d model of a key based on a picture.

I use openCV to perform canny edge detection.

My issue is : how do I convert the edges from canny’s return to a svg

If I find a way to do this my next step would be to convert the svg file to a stl. If possible I would like to do it locally to avoid any security issue like keys travelling from unknown server to unknown server.

Any suggestion could help

I’m on Sdk 32 but the app should work with sdk29.
I can add the apk file I have if needed. I would love this project to be opensource

```
class image_corrector : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_corrector)
    val context = applicationContext
    val imageView: ImageView
    val imageView_clef: ImageView
    val imagevalue: Int
    val retour = findViewById<Button>(R.id.retour_Corr)
    val btnok= findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOK)
    retour.setOnClickListener{
        val intent_retour = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent_retour )}
    btnok.setOnClickListener{val intent_retour = Intent(this, removeBG::class.java)
        startActivity(intent_retour )}
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_imagePrint);
   imageView_clef = findViewById(R.id.image_imagePrint_clef)
    //imageView.drawable.toBitmap()
    val clef: Drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.clef)

    val clefBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.clef)
    //val clefBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(clef.minimumWidth, clef.minimumHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    //



    val imageBitmap = intent.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
    //val imageGrey = makeGray(imageBitmap)

    val edgesImg = Mat()
    val rgba = Mat()
    Utils.bitmapToMat(imageBitmap, rgba)
    val edges = Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1)
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, edges, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4)
    Imgproc.Canny(edges, edges, 80.0, 100.0)

val contours: MutableList<MatOfPoint> = ArrayList()
Imgproc.findContours(
    edges.clone(),
    contours,
    Mat(),
    Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
)
    //Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba,edges,Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    Imgproc.drawContours(edges,contours,0, Scalar(0.0,255.0,0.0),5)



    //imageView.setImageBitmap()


    val resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(edges.cols(), edges.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    Utils.matToBitmap(edges, resultBitmap)
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    imageView_clef.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap)
    val bundle = intent.extras

    if (bundle != null) {
        imagevalue = bundle.getInt("image");
    }
    //imageView.setImageResource(imagevalue);

}
fun makeGray(bitmap: Bitmap) : Bitmap {

    // Create OpenCV mat object and copy content from bitmap
    val mat = Mat()
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat)

    // Convert to grayscale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    // Make a mutable bitmap to copy grayscale image
    val grayBitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.config, true)
    Utils.matToBitmap(mat, grayBitmap)

    return grayBitmap
}


//
```

}

Comment: you need something that *vectorizes* bitmap graphics.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for you're answer. I've find a few libraries doing this. But do you know if I can do it "natively" with Kotlin ?

Comment: I'm here because you tagged `OpenCV`. don't expect me to know any kotlin.